# Is there someway I can get specific details about an AttributeError exception in Python?

Tags: python, exception, attributes, error-handling

I'm trying to call a function.  One of the parameters is a variable with attributes (which I know because of the AttributeError exception I got).  I don't know the exact attributes this variable is supposed to have, so I was wondering if there was some way I can see some extra details about the exception, for example, which attribute it couldn't find.  Thanks.

Comment: It should say what code caused the attribute error in the traceback. You can also look at the source for the function you're calling.

Comment: I do not have the source for the function, which is why this is a problem.

Comment: It is rather hard to call a function in Python that you don't have the source to; is it a C extension? Only a .pyc file?

Comment: Something like that.  It's a program where you are allowed to make your own plugins in python, but there's no documentation.

Comment: @user559495: "Something like that"?  Here's a hint.  Post the actual error message you're actually getting.  All of it.  With information like that, we have to rely on ESP.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`AttributeError` typically identifies the missing attribute. e.g.:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

f = Foo()
print(f.a)
print(f.b)
```

When I run that, I see:

```
$ python foo.py
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(f.b)
AttributeError: Foo instance has no attribute 'b'
```

That's pretty explicit. If you're not seeing something like that, please post the exact error *you're* seeing.

**EDIT**

If you need to force the printing of an exception (for whatever reason), you can do this:

```
import traceback

try:
    # call function that gets AttributeError
except AttributeError:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

That should give you the full error message and traceback associated with the exception.

Comment: I'm not getting a traceback, I was just told that there was an exception.  I had to use try except to find out it was an AttributeError.

Comment: Well, the answer to your question is, "Yes, there *is* a way to tell what attribute is missing. It's right there in the `AttributeError` message." So *now* you have to get the full traceback and message for exception. Print the exception in your `except` clause.

Comment: That's what I did: print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]

Comment: That just printed out AttributeError.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I'm not at my computer at the moment, but I'll try out your solution as soon as possible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The traceback should alert you to the attribute access that raised the [`AttributeError`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.AttributeError) exception:

```
>>> f.b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Foo instance has no attribute 'b'
```

Alternatively, convert the `Exception` to `str`:

```
>>> try:
...     f.b
... except AttributeError, e:
...     print e
... 
Foo instance has no attribute 'b'
```

If you want to get a list of the attributes available on an object, try [`dir()`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/functions.html?highlight=dir#dir) or [`help()`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/functions.html?highlight=help#help)

```
>>> dir(f)
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'a']

>>> help(str)
Help on class str in module __builtin__:

class str(basestring)
 |  str(object) -> string
 |  
 |  Return a nice string representation of the object.
 |  If the argument is a string, the return value is the same object.
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      str
 |      basestring
 |      object
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __add__(...)
 |      x.__add__(y) <==> x+y
 |  
[...]
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data and other attributes defined here:
 |  
 |  __new__ = <built-in method __new__ of type object>
 |      T.__new__(S, ...) -> a new object with type S, a subtype of T
```

You can even call `help()` on `dir` (why is left as an exercise for the reader):

```
>>> help(dir)
Help on built-in function dir in module __builtin__:

dir(...)

dir([object]) -> list of strings

If called without an argument, return the names in the current scope.
Else, return an alphabetized list of names comprising (some of) the attributes
of the given object, and of attributes reachable from it.
If the object supplies a method named __dir__, it will be used; otherwise
the default dir() logic is used and returns:
  for a module object: the module's attributes.
  for a class object:  its attributes, and recursively the attributes
    of its bases.
  for any other object: its attributes, its class's attributes, and
    recursively the attributes of its class's base classes.
```

Failing these... you could always look at the code, unless you've been provided some precompiled module by a third-party, in which case you should demand better documentation (say some unit tests!) from your supplier!

Answer (score 0):

Usually `AttributeError` carries some information about this with it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class SomeClass(object):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sc = SomeClass()
    print sc.fail

#   Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "4572362.py", line 8, in <module>
#     print sc.fail
# AttributeError: 'SomeClass' object has no attribute 'fail'
```

Comment: There is no traceback, unfortunately.

Comment: @user559495: "There is no traceback".  What is there, exactly?